# Was Natan Hanavi associated with any other characters in the Torah?

Tags: king-david, navi-prophets, reincarnation

I am referring to the Natan who rebuked דוד המלך.

Is he associated with other characters via גילגול?

If not, is he compared or contrasted with other characters in mfarshim?

I am basing the idea that he may be on רב מנחם עזריה מפאנו who in his Sefer גילגולי נשמות goes through almost every major character in Jewish history until him and says who else they were.

Comment: This article highlights some parallels to Shmuel: https://lib.cet.ac.il/pages/item.asp?item=14214

Comment: Why would you think he might be?

Comment: As per רב מנחם עזריה most significant characters are

Comment: @zunior Please include this reference (preferably with a precise citation) in your question, so that it'll be clear to readers what context you're operating in.

Comment: Ok but a precise citation isnt required because its his entire sefer